# new version of FF changed order for attributes in input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firefox

I have expected that order for atributes in elements can be changed despite the order in html (only FF 43.0.1). Example:

```html
<input type="checkbox" data-type="can-be-also-empty"/>
```

Please, run snippet in Chrome an then in FF.

Result from devtools:

`<input data-type="can-be-also-empty" type="checkbox"/>` - FF

`<input type="checkbox" data-type="can-be-also-empty"/>` - Chrome

This can be affected with using angular. [Custom directives guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives
>
> The normalization process is as follows: Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.

Thats why i think, if `data-type` atributes going first in element, angular stripping `data-` and it affecting `type="checkbox"` to `type="can-be-also-empty"`.

Next snippet can show better, what i mean:

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('example', function(){
  return {
    template: '<input type="checkbox" data-type="eny-value" ng-model="value"/><p>{{value}}</p>',
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function($scope){
      $scope.value = false;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='app'>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>
  <example></example>
</body>
</html>
```

Also try to run it in FF and Chrome, expression will not be evalueted in FF.

Next step, to move `data-type="eny-value"` before `type`. Now it is not working in any browser.

Comment: The order of attributes shouldn't matter

Comment: @adeneo please, run last code snippet with angular examples in FF and Chrome

Comment: I have no problems with your snippets in either browser

Comment: @kicken please, check version for FF, it should be 43.0.1

Comment: I can see that the attributes are in different order in different browsers, but again, it doesn't matter, attributes have no specified order.

Comment: I am seeing it and looking over a fix for it.

Comment: @adeneo i am agree with you, i am using rappidjs, and according to guide, i should using eg `data-type="toggle"` in input, It is conflict between angular and rappidjs. I should wtrite ticket to guys and describe this issue

Comment: @Jeff do you mean that it is bug for Firefox? now, i dont think so, i did not find it on bugzilla resource.

Comment: @rossoneri it is not working in Firefox 49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from how AngularJS matches directives. In this particular case, it's about `input[checkbox]` it's matches comes from the `type` attribute. According to [AngularJS docs for directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), it can be matched from both `type` and `data-type`, so when angular normalize the data-type, depending on the order of the attributes, it overides de previous value (aka `checkbox`).

This behaviour causes `input[checkbox]` to never work as expected, so then `ngModel` never receives a value of the checked field.

The best approach is to not use such thing, don't use attributes that matches with angularjs normalization.

Comment: thanks for deteiled answer, i agree that solution is not to using same names for atributes